# Rewrite IIS Url's Except App Root

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I hate Regex's and it hates me, here is the problem:

I am dealing with the infamous Angular routing and legacy browsers (IE9+), I have solved all issues but one, which is that in IE the root url for the app requires a forward slash (and only the root).  At the same time I need to remove all forward slashes from other non root requests as demonstrated here in this borrowed snippet:

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)/$" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This works perfectly, I just do not know how to get a request for exactly this: `http://localhost/jumpstart`

Rewritten as: `http://localhost/jumpstart/` with the trailing slash, while preserving the other rule for non app roots requests.

I thought a match of `*\/jumpstart(?!\/)` would suffice, but it fails to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something such as:

```
<rule name="Add trailing slash to jumpstart" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*[^/])$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)jumpstart$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}/" />
</rule>
```

Comment: I am not sure this is working, I enabled logging of the url rewrite: logRewrittenUrl="true"  What I see is: GET /jumpstart - 80

Comment: What happens if you do something such as `"{R:1}\/"` or `"{R:1}&#47;"`?